# NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-sitemaps

Django Noob here.

> **NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml Reverse for 'article_detail' not found. 'article_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

See models.py screenshot (code) to understand the error.

*I don't know what I should put in place of article_details (see the code for explanation).* Your help will appreciable.

**Error-**
[image: NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml]

**Project Structure-**

[image: Project Structure-]

**Code-**

***Dipesh_Pal* Module Code-**

**settings.py-**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
'django.contrib.sites',
]
SITE_ID = 1
```

**urls.py-**
[image: urls.py]

***home* Module Code-**

**sitemaps.py-**
[image: sitemaps.py]

**urls.py-**
[image: urls.py]

**models.py-**
[image: models.py]

> The error in line 37. I am not exactly sure what I should put in place
>   of "article_detail" or I am not sure what exactly wrong in my code.

For your information, I am referring this YouTube video- [Click Here](https://youtu.be/U1f4QTyJBTs)

My Github Repo for this App- [Click Here](https://github.com/Dipeshpal/Dipesh-Pal-Django_Website)

Comment: Here on SO it is expected that you add your code as code-formatted text to the question itself. No links, no screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml Reverse for 'article_detail' not found.
>   'article_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

This means that when it went looking for the view `article_detail` it could not be found. In your `urls.py` you have the line:

`url(r'^(?P<slug>[w\-]+)/$', views.article_detail, name="article-detail")`

You never included your views.py and this the question is in general formatted pretty poorly, but from what we can see it appears you just never declare that view (even though you reference it in the `urls.py`)

EDIT: There is also the possibility that you aren't passing the objects to index in your sitemap when you create the Sitemap, but again.. As the formatting isn't everything we need. We can only speculate.

So, definitely check that `article_detail` is working in general. If it is, go to where you are creating the data for your Sitemap object and make sure that you're passing an object with the url.

Comment: I created `article_detail` view and when I hit that article_detail URL, it's working fine.

Comment: Happy to hear! You should upvote my answer and mark this as answered so that others don't stumble upon this and think that your answer wasn't found :)